# breaking a tabular and aligning tabulars throughout the document

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have two questions.

1. How do you break a tabular so that some of it lies on the previous page while the rest is on the next page. See sample tex file provided below.
2. How do you align the tabular so that columns in (separate) tables are spaced out evenly throughout the document?

You need the resume LaTeX Class File in here: file http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/4/cv_4.zip

Thank you.

Sample tex file:

```
\documentclass{resume} 

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.7in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}  


\begin{document}




Testing, hello, hello. This is a sample tex file provided to StackExchange. 

\textbf{University of So and So}  
\hfill  
                \vspace{-2mm}                                                                                                                                                       \vspace{-3mm}\\\vspace{-1mm}%

\begin{tabular}{lll}  
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                    
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\    
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\    
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
\end{tabular} 

I will insert some sentences here. But then afterwards, more tabulars will be inserted as one can see below. 

\begin{tabular}{lll}         
        Spring 2014, Summer 2014, Fall 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\    
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\    
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lll}        
        Fall 2013- Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                            
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
      \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                            
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}. 
          \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                            
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}. 
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}. 
          \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\                            
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.  
            \vspace{2mm}  \\ 
        Spring 2014 & Math & Calculus, \textsl{recitations}.        
\end{tabular}                     







\end{document}
```

Comment: use the longtable environment from the package of the same name.

Comment: for your second question the [eqparbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package could help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! The longtable environment automatically cuts off tables when there isn't enough space on one page. To those who are confused, just add \usepackage{longtable} and then replace all "tabular" with "longtable".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's solved in comments using the `longtable` package as stated by OP also in comments